# Radius and center of a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, circles

If there is a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$, for example: 
$(\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{2}-\sin\phi},\frac{\sin\phi}{\sqrt{2}-\sin\phi},\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{2}-\sin\phi})$ where $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$ (Which looks like a circle, according to my plot in wolfram mathematica) How can I calculate its radius and center? Calculating the squares of the coordinates does not give constans. Is there any general method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: Call $\gamma(t)$ the parametrization of your curve. Then set $P=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and compute the difference
$$
\|\gamma(t)-P\|^2\;,
$$
trying to find the coordinate for $P$ such that the above quantity results constant wrt $t$.

Answer (score 0):

We try to find two algebraic dependencies between the coordinates of the points on the curve. The first is obvious, $x=z$, the second with some help from [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7B%20(a-v)x%20-u,%20(a-v)y-v,%20(a-v)z-u,%20u%5E2%2Bv%5E2-1%7D,%20%7Bx,y,z,a%7D,%7Bu,v%7D%5D) :
$$x^2 + (y-1)^2 + z^2 = 2$$

Another approach: solve and get
$$\cos \phi = \frac{\sqrt{2}\, x}{y+1}\\
\sin \phi= \frac{\sqrt{2}\, y}{y+1}$$
so $2 x^2 + 2 y^2 =(y+1)^2$, and using $x=z$ we get the same equation as above. Note that every point on the circle except $(0,-1,0)$ is covered, and exactly once.